# Create a view in D7 that displays and links the taxanomy term and displays and links nodes associated with the term

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms

I'm trying to build out a HTML list menu of taxonomy term followed by nodes associated to that term as a sub HTML list. All items should be linked as well. Can this be done?

Example below:

- Taxonomy Term 1

  - Associated Node 1
  - Associated Node 2
  - Associated Node 3
- Taxonomy Term 2

  - Associated Node 4
  - Associated Node 5
  - Associated Node 6
  - Associated Node 7
  - Associated Node 8
  - Associated Node 9
- Taxonomy Term 3

  - Associated Node 10
  - Associated Node 11
- Taxonomy Term 4

Comment: Of course it is :) did you try writing a custom query to fetch all information you need? Which part are you stuck on?

Comment: @AramBoyajyan - I was going to respond but it looks like No Sssweat gave me the answer I was looking for. My thought was to not have to do it by writing out code for it. Rather go through the views module to accomplish the task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### [Views tree](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_tree)

> This module provides a tree-based style plugin for Views. It is
> equivalent to the tree-based style template from Views 1.
>
> It is based off of the list style. Although it generates a nested
> view, there is still only a single query run for the view making it
> quite performant.
>
> #### Compatibility
>
> This module has been tested and used with the following
> relationship-oriented modules:
>
> - Taxonomy (in core) - parent/child relationships References - node and
>   user references Relation
> - references between any entities (D7 only)
> - Entity reference - references between any entities (D7 only)
> - Organic Groups (D7 only)
>
> Example:
>
> [image]